# Confusion about setting up developer environemnt for mattermost

Tags: docker

Im trying to set up developer environment for the opensource github repo for Mattermost-Server and i am confused about how to do step 4 (https://developers.mattermost.com/contribute/server/developer-setup/). Also, under step 1, after i have installed docker, it says 'First, Backup from any existing containers' and when i type that stuff in command prompt with docker, i get an error. How do i run those commands?

Comment: What error do you get? What is unclear about step 4?

Comment: For step 4, how do i set up the environment variables? should i just go to Environment variables in system properties and add paths for 'System Variables'? or do i run these commands in powershell?